# Django database settings SERVER keyword SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django, driver

I'm getting an error after installing the Microsoft Database driver for linux/ unix. Django is throwing this error:

`Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied`

Is there a way to pass in the SERVER and DSN to the settings.py file to get the connection string Django creates to be properly configured?

Comment: maybe this ?; https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet I’m using Django-pyodbc and Django-pyodbc-azure. Could I swap them out for Django-mssql instead?

Answer (score 0):

Its crazy but I managed to solve it by actually passing an option: extra_params: server=WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\DBSERVER

I am using it pyodbc on django BTW. Must be some bug where django actually passes HOST instead of SERVER into the connection string.

something like this would work.

```
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'YOURGREATESTDATABASE',
    'USER': 'YOURGREATESTUSERNAME',
    'PASSWORD': 'YOURGREATESTPASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\DBSERVER',
    'PORT': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'extra_params': "Persist Security Info=False;server=WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\\DBSERVER"
```